# Update Loop clarification

Tags: loops, updates

It was recently brought to my attention that inside a game update loop, functions will not be completely run before another loop of update. for instance:

```
void update()
{
function 1;
function 2;
}
```

before function 1 or function 2 have completely run another update loop will be called.
Is this the case? Since i have always thought it wasn't looped again until the end of functions have been run.
As i have never been taught this and until recently never had to look this up, i have never coded with this in mind. 
i find this strange because now it seems that if i want a piece of code to run on each frame i have to literally put the code in the update loop.
e.g

```
void update()
{
int i = 0;
int j - 0;
etc //the contents of function a
}
```

My problem with this is that surely this will stop polymorphism and encapsulation? In the way that i would create a function rather than repeat a piece of code.

Am i correct and if so why?

Comment: Not quite sure what programming language you're talking about but normally you would have a void frame() { do this } function that is completely executed each call. Which is not what you have heard.

Comment: the code is was talking about above is C# XNA game studio, but the problem arose with UnityScript and there onGUI function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I am not sure of the programming language which you are using.

1. However, you are dealing with the case of [re-entrant/non-re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29). When signals are issued then the current flow will be 'with-held' and the action on the signal will be called (read it as interrupt). In case the action of the signal is to call the same function (in your case update function), then you can have the effect of - hold and call again in the same thread.
2. One more possibility is if your system is multi-threaded. Then you current thread execution path can be with-held and any other thread execution can be called. This in-turn can call the update function again.

These two are very famous basic computer science concept and are referred as re-entrant and thread-safety'ness of a function. This [book (APIU)](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/unix/9780321638014) personally is an amazing book - try to get a copy of it.